# my R data frame outputs variables in the wrong order

Tags: r, dataframe, variables

I made the following data frame in R:

```
d <- data.frame(
  virtue=factor(c("Flexibility", "Attends to detail", "Completes work on time", "Follows instructions",
                    "Work ethic", "Productivity", "Quality of work")), 
  status=factor(c("No ASD", "ASD")),
  standard=factor(c("Above", "Meets", "Below")),
  amount=c(30.2, 61.5, 8.3,
           19.6, 52.9, 27.5,
           19.0, 70.5, 10.5,
           54.9, 37.3, 7.8,
           21.3, 71.3, 7.5,
           37.3, 47.1, 15.7,
           29.8, 66.0, 4.3,
           27.5, 58.8, 13.7,
           30.1, 62.4, 7.5,
           70.6, 23.5, 5.9,
           24.5, 67.0, 8.5,
           34.0, 52.0, 14.0,
           25.9, 68.8, 5.4,
           41.2, 52.9, 5.9)
)
```

The output looks like this for the first six rows:

```
  virtue status standard amount
1             Flexibility No ASD    Above   30.2
2       Attends to detail    ASD    Meets   61.5
3  Completes work on time No ASD    Below    8.3
4    Follows instructions    ASD    Above   19.6
5              Work ethic No ASD    Meets   52.9
6            Productivity    ASD    Below   27.5
```

This is not the output I was expecting. I need the data frame to look like this:

```
Flexibility     No ASD     Above     30.2
Flexibility     No ASD     Meets     61.5
Flexibility     No ASD     Below     8.3
Flexibility        ASD     Above     19.6
Flexibility        ASD     Meets     52.9
Flexibility        ASD     Below     27.5
```

and then continue on in the same order for the other "virtue" variables.

Is it not possible to make the date frame do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution with `rep()` inside your dataframe:

```
#Code
d <- data.frame(
  virtue=factor(rep(c("Flexibility", "Attends to detail", "Completes work on time", "Follows instructions",
                      "Work ethic", "Productivity", "Quality of work"),each=6)), 
  status=factor(rep(c("No ASD", "ASD"),each=3)),
  standard=factor(c("Above", "Meets", "Below")),
  amount=c(30.2, 61.5, 8.3,
           19.6, 52.9, 27.5,
           19.0, 70.5, 10.5,
           54.9, 37.3, 7.8,
           21.3, 71.3, 7.5,
           37.3, 47.1, 15.7,
           29.8, 66.0, 4.3,
           27.5, 58.8, 13.7,
           30.1, 62.4, 7.5,
           70.6, 23.5, 5.9,
           24.5, 67.0, 8.5,
           34.0, 52.0, 14.0,
           25.9, 68.8, 5.4,
           41.2, 52.9, 5.9)
)
```

Output (some rows):

```
                   virtue status standard amount
1             Flexibility No ASD    Above   30.2
2             Flexibility No ASD    Meets   61.5
3             Flexibility No ASD    Below    8.3
4             Flexibility    ASD    Above   19.6
5             Flexibility    ASD    Meets   52.9
6             Flexibility    ASD    Below   27.5
```

Comment: Thank you Duck your solution gave me just what I needed

Comment: @JenniferB. Amazing Jennifer ! If you thing this answer was useful you could accept it by clicking the tick on the left side of this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

`data.frame` has no idea about what you are trying to do, it is simply using R's rules about vector recycling. It will just repeat the vectors you gave until they are long enough to fit into a dataframe with that many values in `amount`.

You probably want to use `expand.grid`, which makes all combinations of values:

```
d <- expand.grid(
  standard = factor(c("Above", "Meets", "Below")),
  status = factor(c("No ASD", "ASD")),
  virtue = factor(c("Flexibility", "Attends to detail", "Completes work on time", "Follows instructions",
                  "Work ethic", "Productivity", "Quality of work"))
)
```

Note that the order of arguments to `expand.grid` matters, the last argument is cycled slowest.

Then assign the `amount`:

```
d$amount <- 
  c(30.2, 61.5, 8.3,
    19.6, 52.9, 27.5,
    19.0, 70.5, 10.5,
    54.9, 37.3, 7.8,
    21.3, 71.3, 7.5,
    37.3, 47.1, 15.7,
    29.8, 66.0, 4.3,
    27.5, 58.8, 13.7,
    30.1, 62.4, 7.5,
    70.6, 23.5, 5.9,
    24.5, 67.0, 8.5,
    34.0, 52.0, 14.0,
    25.9, 68.8, 5.4,
    41.2, 52.9, 5.9)
```

Result:

```
head(d, 10)
```

> ```
>    standard status            virtue amount
> 1     Above No ASD       Flexibility   30.2
> 2     Meets No ASD       Flexibility   61.5
> 3     Below No ASD       Flexibility    8.3
> 4     Above    ASD       Flexibility   19.6
> 5     Meets    ASD       Flexibility   52.9
> 6     Below    ASD       Flexibility   27.5
> 7     Above No ASD Attends to detail   19.0
> 8     Meets No ASD Attends to detail   70.5
> 9     Below No ASD Attends to detail   10.5
> 10    Above    ASD Attends to detail   54.9
> ```